# My Javascript code doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var audio, playbtn, mutebtn, seek_bar;

function initAudioPlayer() {
  audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = "nineDays.mp3";
  audio.loop = true;
  audio.play();
  // Set object references
  playbtn = document.getElementById("playpausebtn");
  mutebtn = document.getElementById("mutebtn");
  // Add Event Handling
  playbtn.addEventListener("click", playPause);
  mutebtn.addEventListener("click", mute);
  // Functions
  function playPause() {
    if (audio.paused) {
      audio.play();
      playbtn.style.background = "url(video_pause.png) no-repeat";
    } else {
      audio.pause();
      playbtn.style.background = "url(play.png) no-repeat";
    }
  }

  function mute() {
    if (audio.muted) {
      audio.muted = false;
      mutebtn.style.background = "url(speaker.png) no-repeat";
    } else {
      audio.muted = true;
      mutebtn.style.background = "url(mute.png) no-repeat";
    }
  }
}
window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);
```

```css
body {
  background: #282828;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 80%;
  margin-right: 50%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
}
.container {
  padding-top: 8%;
}
button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
button#playpausebtn {
  background: url(video_pause.png) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-left: 20px;
  marging-top: 35px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
}
button#mutebtn {
  background: url(speaker.png) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top: 35px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
}
.soundNav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="soundNav">
    <button id="playpausebtn"></button>

    <button id="mutebtn"></button>
  </div>



  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="Final%20project.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="page2.html">About me</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="page3.html">Work</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="contactme.html">Get In Touch</a>
    </li>
  </ul>


  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">

        <div id="my-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

          <!--Indicators dot nav-->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#my-slider" data-slide-to="3"></li>
          </ol>

          <!--wrapper for slides-->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="1.jpg" alt="Ed Sheeran Concert, Blossom Center, August2016" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1> © Ed Sheeran Concert at Blossom Center</br>
                                August 2015
               </h1>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="5.jpg" alt="Ed Sheeran Concert, Blossom Center, August2016" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>  </br>
               </h1>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <img src="6.jpg" alt="Ed Sheeran Concert, Blossom Center, August2016" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>  </br>
               </h1>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item ">
              <img src="2.jpg" alt="Ed Sheeran Concert, Blossom Center, August2016" />
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1> </h1>

              </div>
            </div>
            <!--controls or next and prev buttons-->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>

            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#my-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>








          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>








  </div>


</body>










</html>
```

I am trying to understand what the problem is- whenever someone opens the page, the music starts. I want the user to be able to pause or mute the music whenever they want to. And that works fine, except my icons won't show, it's as they are hidden. Everything is in the same folder. I was thinking to use glyphicons, but I don't know how to use them inside of the javascript.

Comment: You don't use glyphicons "inside of the javascript". You display them, usually, using a CSS class. Have you looked in your console (hit F12) for any errors?

Comment: http://stacksnippets.net/speaker.png, 404 not found. Same with other images

Comment: I looked in the console and there are no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the javascript style syntax is littlebit different. use

```
mutebtn.style.backgroundImage = "url('mute.png') no-repeat";
```

and make sure ./mute.png exists and is readable

Comment: Now the code works properly, but my icons won't update whenever I click them. They exists and they are readable as well.